# Need help in tweaking the json response using Karate

Tags: karate

Is there a possibility to tweak the output 1 to output 2 ?

```
* def dataset = databaseMethods.runJsonQuery(result, query) 
* def output1 = dataset
Then print dataset
* def output2 = { "recordset": "#(output1)" }
```

Then print output2

```
Expected output what I need: { "recordset": [ [{"Account no" :"123", "Key" : "9989"}, {"Account no" :"345", "Key" : "9889"},{"Account no :"569", "Key" : "9989"}] }
```

Actual output its getting printed :

```
{"recordset": "[ [{\"Account no\" :\"123\", \"Key\" : \"9989\"}, {\"Account no\" :\"345\", \"Key\" : \"9889\"},{\"Account no\" :\"569\", \"Key\" : \"9989\"}] }
```

Please let me know how to tweak json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a string where you need JSON. Read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

So you can do this:

```
* json output1 = dataset
```